# pi-4 cryptsetup benchmark output?

Tags: pi-4

On the pi-4 what is the output of "cryptsetup benchmark"?

I want to asses its performance compared to the pi-3.
Apparently the new "quality standards" require this question to be needlessly verbose thus these 2 extra sentences.

Comment: Does this wiki book help? ( https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptsetup )

Comment: My apologies.  I actually read your question a couple of times. My English and IQ are both a bit low.  You mentioned "two extra sentences".  Did I miss your more detailed question somewhere?

Comment: I already ordered two Pi4s a week ago, and they should arrive any time.   And I am interested to learn new things. Should I still need to delete my comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=149&t=30103&p=215037

```
Algorithm | Key. | Encryption. | Decryption
aes-xts.  | 512b | 66.1 MiB/s. | 56.8 MiB/s.
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit too brief.  I only know about Windows PGP so do not have enough knowledge to understand CrySteup.  Anyway, when my Pi4 arrives, I can study the following tutorial and try to encrypt my data partitions: "How to encrypt partitions using LUKS - WikiBooks" (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptsetup).

Answer (score 2):

Stock Raspberry Pi 4B has a little underwhelming cryptsetup performance. Unfortunately it doesn't have hardware AES acceleration

```
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).

PBKDF2-sha1       357631 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256     571742 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512     471482 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  296207 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  107084 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       4 iterations, 322760 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      4 iterations, 323296 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b        23.8 MiB/s        46.7 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-cbc        128b               N/A               N/A
        aes-cbc        256b        17.4 MiB/s        34.1 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-cbc        256b               N/A               N/A
        aes-xts        256b        54.1 MiB/s        46.0 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-xts        256b               N/A               N/A
        aes-xts        512b        40.1 MiB/s        33.7 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-xts        512b               N/A               N/A
```

If you overclock and and overvolt you can see mild improvments
After rebooting with these settings in /boot/config.txt

```
arm_freq=2000
over_voltage=6
```

I got:

```
root@pi-admin:~# cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).

PBKDF2-sha1       477493 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256     776722 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512     639375 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  395987 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  143091 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       4 iterations, 328696 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      4 iterations, 329115 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b        30.6 MiB/s        61.0 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-cbc        128b               N/A               N/A
        aes-cbc        256b        22.8 MiB/s        44.5 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-cbc        256b               N/A               N/A
        aes-xts        256b        69.9 MiB/s        60.1 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-xts        256b               N/A               N/A
        aes-xts        512b        52.4 MiB/s        44.1 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b               N/A               N/A
    twofish-xts        512b               N/A               N/A
root@pi-admin:~#
```